# When typing yarn start in the terminal an error occurs stating /bin/sh: nodemon: command not found Command failed with exit code 127 comes up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, rest, mern

My json package is below

```
{
  "name": "node-rest-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.3"
  }
}
```

I have exhausted all solutions I have found as most of them point to me having start in my json package which I already do so,

Comment: What appears after yarn start command -> yarn run v1.22.17
$ nodemon index.js
/bin/sh: nodemon: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: Yow Bro. You need to install nodemon `npm i nodemon `

Answer (score 1):

Because nodemon module is not installed

either install manually by below command

```
npm i nodemon
```

or add nodemon in pakage.json

```
{
  "name": "node-rest-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.3",
  }
"devDependencies": {
     "nodemon" : "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

and after that `npm install`

Comment: Thank you soooo much it solved it, and thanks for you clear instructions!

Comment: please upvote and marked it as answered if it solved your issue

Comment: better if nodemon is installed as a dev dependancy

Comment: @cmgchess by default if we installed it from cli it will add as a dev dependencies, nonetheless i've updated the answer